# generalized binomial coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I know that the coefficient $$-\frac{1}{2} \choose k$$ can be simplified by multiplying both the nominator and the denominator by $$2^k$$ and then represented as $$ (-\frac{1}{4})^k {2k\choose k}$$
But what if the upper index is $$\frac{1}{3}$$it seems that our trick do not work anymore, is there anything we can do about it?

Comment: A natural generalization of the binomial coefficients to reals is provided by the Beta function. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There is no nice generalisation from $\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{k}$ to $\binom{\pm \frac{1}{n}}{k}, 0\leq k \leq n$ available.
>
> We obtain for $n=2$:
>
> \begin{align*}
>   \binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{k}&=\frac{1}{k!}
>     \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)\cdots\left(-\frac{1}{2}-(k-1)\right)\\
>     &=\frac{1}{k!}\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k}(2k-1)!!\\
>     &=\frac{1}{k!}\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k}\frac{(2k)!}{(2k)!!}\tag{1}\\
>     &=\frac{(-1)^k}{2^{2k}}\frac{(2k)!}{k!k!}\\
>     &=\frac{(-1)^k}{2^{2k}}\binom{2k}{k}\\
>   \end{align*}
>
> and for $n=3$:
>
> \begin{align*}
>   \binom{-\frac{1}{3}}{k}&=\frac{1}{k!}
>     \left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(-\frac{4}{3}\right)\cdots\left(-\frac{1}{3}-(k-1)\right)\\
>     &=\frac{1}{k!}\frac{(-1)^k}{3^k}(3k-2)!!!\\
>     &=\frac{1}{k!}\frac{(-1)^k}{3^k}\frac{(3k)!}{(3k)!!!(3k-1)!!!}\tag{2}\\
>     &=\frac{(-1)^k}{3^{2k}}\frac{(3k)!}{k!k!}\frac{1}{(3k-1)!!!}\\
>     &=\frac{(-1)^k}{3^{2k}}\binom{3k}{2k}\binom{2k}{k}\frac{1}{(3k-1)!!!}\\
>   \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the *[double factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial)*

\begin{align*}
  (2k)!&=(2k)!!(2k-1)!!\qquad \text{and} \qquad (2k)!!=2^kk!\\
  \end{align*}

- The formula with *triple factorials* in (2) is somewhat more complicated due to additional factors $(3k-1)!!!$

\begin{align*}
  (3k)!&=(3k)!!!(3k-1)!!!(3k-2)!!!\qquad \text{and} \qquad (3k)!!!=3^kk!\\
  \end{align*}

*Note:* You might find the generalisation to $\binom{\alpha}{k}$ with $\alpha \in\mathbb{C}, k\geq 0$ used in *[binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* or the even more *[generalized binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)* based upon Gamma functions useful.